# Smoother Page Slide in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

Working on a cross-platform mobile webapp, and using jQuery Mobile (Alpha, I know) for front-end. Is there anyway to smooth the sliding transition from one page to another? Whenever a link in a listview is tapped, it's like 10 or 15 pixels of padding are added to the page, and everything (including the header) is shifted down until it readjusts on the new page. I've searched everywhere, and can't seem to find a definitive solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Test it with a simple page that contains only text and links in header,footer and content divs and see if it happens then. 
I expect it to be caused by some html you added. If not - it's a bug in jquery mobile.

You could publish an example if you can't work it out.